# why won't my apps go to sd card

Tags: sd-card, insufficient-memory

I have a tablet that has little memory and I needed an sd card so I got one, but I still have 29 GB on the sd card and when I try to download an app it says insufficient memory because I ran out of room on my internal storage

Comment: Well, can you tell us which Android version you are running? If you are running Kitkat then you are getting the error because it deosn't allows moving application to the SD card !

Comment: 4.4.2 is the version I'm running

Comment: Well, in that case I don't think you can transfer your apps over to the SD card until or unless you have rooted your device !

Comment: Brandon, I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag to your question. Please check [its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first aid and further hints. Apart from that: Your issue not being able to move apps to the card might be related to Kitkat's changes concerning SD card access. Few manufacturers fixed that for their devices, but most stopped providing the app2sd feature even before that.

Answer (score 1):

Hey do you have selected your default write disk to your sd card in settings? If not go to settings>storage and select sd card in menu. Have you got root? If you have root, then you can move every application to sd card. Try titanium backup. And if you are on android 4.0+ then you cant just move all applications to sd card. Some apps are suggested to keep in internal storage for working correctly. Just download app2sd and move the movable apps to SD card.

Comment: If you have done that before, then tell us the android version of your device. Is it a -4.0 android or  +4.0 android.

Comment: 4.4.2 is the version I'm running

Comment: It is 4.4.2 and ok I'll download that

Comment: I done have an option to "move to sd" in my settings and all the apps  that are app2sd just bring me back to settings

Comment: Thats the problem. Its android 4.4.2 google decided to keep some apps on internal so that they can work properly without any damage or lagging as on sd card.

Answer (score 1):

I had already provided you an answer but I think that you are not satisfied with it because it was for the rooted android. Now, I want to say that you can also move some apps(not all) to SD card using some app moving applications like app2sd, du speed booster etc. These are some simple applications which simply transfers the movable applications to SD card(only movable). You can also do it in settings but in these applications, you can do them together. If you want to move all applications, there is not any way to do that because without rooting, only your movable apps can be moved. If any other problem, just comment it.